# How can private inheritance from a visitor interface allow a visitable object to access visit private visit implementations?

Tags: c++, inheritance, private, visitor-pattern

The following code shows a class which privately inherits from an interface having its private functions accessed without granting the calling object friendship. I am baffled by this but can't really see what better solution the compiler could come up with (code compiles and runs). Why does this work?

```
#include <iostream>

class IVisitor;

class IVisitable
{
public:
    virtual void Accept(IVisitor& visitor) const = 0;
};

class VisitableA;
class VisitableB;

class IVisitor
{
public:

    virtual void Visit(const VisitableA& a) = 0;

    virtual void Visit(const VisitableB& b) = 0;
};

class VisitableA : public IVisitable
{
public:
    virtual void Accept(IVisitor& visitor) const
    {
        visitor.Visit(*this);
    }
};

class VisitableB : public IVisitable
{
public:
    virtual void Accept(IVisitor& visitor) const
    {
        visitor.Visit(*this);
    }
};

class PrivateVisitor : private IVisitor
{
public:
    PrivateVisitor(IVisitable& v)
    {
        v.Accept(*this);    
    }

private:

    virtual void Visit(const VisitableA& a)
    {
        std::cout << "I saw A\n";
    }

    virtual void Visit(const VisitableB& b)
    {
        std::cout << "I saw B\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
VisitableA a;
VisitableB b;

PrivateVisitor p_a(a);
PrivateVisitor p_b(b);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access specifiers are only checked at compile time, and there they are checked on the static type of the object on which they are applied.

Inside `PrivateVisitor` constructor, the `*this` object is casted to `IVisitor`. In this context the type of inheritance does not matter, as we are within the `PrivateVisitor` type, so we have full access.

The object is used inside the `IVisitable` object (`VisitableA` or `VisitableB`) and the `Visit` member function is called. While the *dynamic* type of the object is `PrivateVisitor`, the *static* type is `IVisitor` (the reference is of type `IVisitor&`). Access specifiers are checked against `IVisitor` class where both `Visit` overloads are *public*, so the compiler accepts the call.

The fact that the function is *private* in the final overrider does not really matter, as access was performed through the base class, where the functions are *public*.

Answer (score 1):

The private that matters here, is this one:

```
PrivateVisitor : private IVisitor
```

Luckily, the only place where a PrivateVisitor is casted to a IVisitor, is the constructor:

```
PrivateVisitor::PrivateVisitor(IVisitable& v)
{
    v.Accept(*this);
}
```

And the constructor has access to the private bases of the class.

Answer (score 0):

private is at the class scope, not the object scope.